# json response in in correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf

i am using this code

```
    public static string myjson(bool a)
    {
        if (a == true)
        {
            RootObject o = new RootObject();

            o.success = "true";
            o.firstname = "anurag";
            o.usertype = "admin";
            o.userid = "123";
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
             string d=serializer.Serialize(o);
             return d;

        }
        else
        {
            errormessage o = new errormessage();

              o.success = "false";
            o.message = "invalid username or password";
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
           string p=serializer.Serialize(o);
            return p.ToString();


        }
    }
```

when i host my web service on iis and excess this service i get response

```
      {"checkuserResult":" {\"success\":\"true\",\"firstname\":\"anurag\",\"userid\":\"123\",\"usertype\":\"admin\"}"}
```

what i want as return is just the json response

```
       {"success":"true","firstname":"anurag","userid":"123","usertype":"admin"}
```

please help?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the code where your string of json is returned to the client. The bug is likely there.

Comment: @user3771185 \" They are escaping characters. If you view in debug mode it show like., But the output is valid json.,

Comment: @user3771185 Change the `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` in Operation contract - WCF

Comment: it helped thirisangu now the output is "{\"success\":\"true\",\"firstname\":\"anurag\",\"userid\":\"123\",\"usertype\":\"admin\"}"
but still the slash are not removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to use JSON.Net.Far better than JavascriptSerializer and you can control the behaviour very much.

Install Nuget first:

> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

And then call

> var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);